# JSX dot notation with forwardRef typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to figure out the types for Dot Notation components with forwardRef.

So I found this example which perfectly illustrates how I currently use dot notation, but doesn't include forwardRef: https://codesandbox.io/s/stpkm

This is what I'm trying to achieve, but can't figure out the typings.

```
import { forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from "react";
//
import { ForwardRefRenderFunction } from "react";

const TabToggle: React.FC = () => null;
const TabContent: React.FC = () => null;

interface TabsStatic {
  Toggle: typeof TabToggle;
  Content: typeof TabContent;
}

export interface TabsProps {
  initialIndex?: number;
}

export interface TabsRefMethods {
  show: () => null;
  hide: () => null;
}

export const Tabs: React.ForwardRefRenderFunction<
  TabsRefMethods,
  TabsProps & TabsStatic
> = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const openFn = () => null;
  const closeFn = () => null;
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ show: openFn, hide: closeFn }));
  return null;
});

Tabs.Toggle = TabToggle;
Tabs.Content = TabContent;
```

**Code Sandbox Demo**: https://codesandbox.io/s/jsx-dot-notation-in-typescript-with-react-forked-38e1z?file=/src/Tabs.tsx

Comment: You simply made a small typo. You wrote `TabsProps & TabsStatic>` instead of `TabsProps> & TabsStatic`. With that change everything should work. Maybe you will need to do `forwardRef(...) as any`, but I do not see a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possible approaches I'm aware of and have used. Both have slightly different tradeoffs.

The first is to interset (`&`) the static components and mark them as optional (`Partial`) so that there isn't an error when declaring the component. The downside is that they are denoted as optional even though they are always set.

```js
import * as React from "react";

const TabToggle: React.FC = () => null;
const TabContent: React.FC = () => null;

interface TabsStatic {
  Toggle: typeof TabToggle;
  Content: typeof TabContent;
}

export interface TabsProps {
  initialIndex?: number;
}

export interface TabsRefMethods {
  show: () => null;
  hide: () => null;
}

export const Tabs: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  React.PropsWithoutRef<TabsProps> & React.RefAttributes<TabsRefMethods>
> &
  Partial<TabsStatic> = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => null);

Tabs.Toggle = TabToggle;
Tabs.Content = TabContent;
```

The alternative is to make them required, but this requires a cast. The resulting type is more accurate, but it does require a cast.

```js
type TabsComponent = React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
  React.PropsWithoutRef<TabsProps> & React.RefAttributes<TabsRefMethods>
> &
  TabsStatic;

export const Tabs = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => null) as TabsComponent;

Tabs.Toggle = TabToggle;
Tabs.Content = TabContent;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have actually managed to use something very similar to your method 1, subcomponents would appear as `ReactComponent | undefined`, not allowing me to use the subcomponents in JSX. I used it to suppress the errors though.
`export const Tabs: typeof TabsWithForwardRef & Partial<TabsRefMethods> = TabsWithForwardRef;`

Thanks for the cast approach, I think most of the stuff works with this approach.

Answer (score 10):

There is much easier way to achieve the same result:

```
const Flex = React.forwardRef(function Flex(...) {
  ...
})

const FlexRow = React.forwardRef(...)
const FlexColumn = React.forwardRef(...)

const FlexNamespace = Object.assign(Flex, {Row: FlexRow, Column: FlexColumn})

export {FlexNamespace as Flex}
```

Now you can use `Flex`, `Flex.Row`, and `Flex.Column` with TS being happy. The magic line is `Object.assign` which
does not cause the same type issue as `Flex.Row = FlexRow` does. Don't ask me why, I just accidentally found this

Answer (score 1):

Or even shorter:

```
const TabsComponent = () => {
  // implement the Tabs component
};

const TabContentComponent = () => {
  // implement the TabContent component
};

const TabToggleComponent = () => {
  // implement the TabToggle component
};

export const Tabs = Object.assign(forwardRef(TabsComponent),
  // a component with forward refs
  TabContent: forwardRef(TabContentComponent),

  // a component without forwarding
  TabToggle
};
```

Comment: very clean solution and works with JSX!